# DI does not work when WebApi is hosted in memory in separate assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

so basically I'm writing small web api application using .net framework 4.8. It works fine, and I thought that I will write also some integration tests. So I created separated project, let's say DummyTests. Then I'm creating in-memory host and run some requests like:

```
var client = new HttpClient(server);
var request = createRequest("api/user/all", "application/json", HttpMethod.Get);
using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result)
{
    //...
}
```

Unfortunately I'm always getting error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DummyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

My server setup:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "Default", routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;

WebApiConfig.Register(config);
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(unityContainer);
Core.UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(unityContainer);

server = new HttpServer(config);
```

As you can see, I'm also assigning DI to my config object.

It only works when I move my tests to same project where WebApi, but I wanted to keep tests in separate assembly. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have not heard about assembly dependent DI container problems. Do you have your container configuration code (server setup) executed when test is running?

Comment: @oleksa I.e. Unity (like in this case) would not automatically pick up `internal` classes from other assemblies... But to figure the problem described in this post one likely would need [MCVE]...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  It should not be a problem . DI configuration code in the server assembly will have access for all internal classes in the server assembly for sure. But server DI configuration code must be executed before testing the in-memory server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've already solve my issue. During the testing I've tried resolve one of my respositories from unity container. And I got error that one of my nuget package cannot be loaded beacuse of version mismatch(different in test assembly and in WebApi assembly). After I fixed it, everything works fine.